# In R: dbGetQuery() coerces a string to a numeric and causes problems

Tags: r, sqlite

I have a table in a sqlite database with the following schema

```
CREATE TABLE os_logs (version STRING, user STRING, date STRING);
```

I set the following command to a variable called `cmd`.

```
select count(*), version
  from os_logs
  group by version
  order by version;
```

After I send that command through dbGetQuery I get numeric results back for version instead of a string.

```
db <- dbConnect(SQLite(),"./os_backup.db")
dbGetQuery(db,cmd)

count(*)    version
1421    NA
1797    0.7
6   0.71
2152    0.71
1123    0.72
3455    1
2335    1
```

The versions should be

```
0.70.1111_Product
0.71.22_Dev
0.71.33_Product
...
```

Any idea on why the strings in my sqlite database are being turned into numerics in R?  If I do that command on the sql cmd line it works perfectly

Edit:
Here is how the tables are created.  (With more info since I edited it out in the original question.

```
drop table vocf_logs;

CREATE TABLE vocf_logs (version STRING, driver STRING, dir STRING, uuid STRING PRIMARY KEY, t_start STRING);
CREATE TABLE log_os (uuid STRING PRIMARY KEY, os STRING);

.separator ","
.import vocf_dirs.csv vocf_logs

-- Put the OsVersion info from name_redacted into the table
UPDATE vocf_logs
SET version=(select log_os.os from log_os where uuid = vocf_logs.uuid);
```

Comment: Which package do you use? Is it `RSQLite`? Also, could you post an example of how you insert the data? It shouldn't happen as you say it does given what you have in the question.

Comment: RSQLite.  I added more info.   I had an excel table that was 27k rows and growing with no intent to stop so I switched over to sqlite database.  This was the sequence used to put it into a db.  The os version had to be merged in from a 2nd effort

Comment: Figured it out.  The data type on table creation was wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The creation of the original table was wrong.  The method in R was correct.   From the data type descriptions found here: https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html.

```
The declared type of "STRING" has an affinity of NUMERIC, not TEXT.
```

When table was created using type TEXT it worked as expected.

Answer (score 2):

What you describe should work fine. You must have done something differently or inserted it incorrectly to the db.

Here is a step by step test that does the exact same and works:

```
# Load package and connect
R> library(RSQLite)    
R> db <- dbConnect(SQLite(),"./os_backup.db")

# Create db and insert data
R> dbSendQuery(db, "CREATE TABLE os_logs (version STRING, user STRING, date STRING);")
R> dbSendQuery(db, "INSERT INTO os_logs VALUES ('0.70.1111_Product', 'while', '2015-04-23')")
R> dbSendQuery(db, "INSERT INTO os_logs VALUES ('0.70.1111_Product', 'while', '2015-04-24')")
R> dbSendQuery(db, "INSERT INTO os_logs VALUES ('0.71.22_Dev', 'while', '2015-04-24')")

# Run query counting versions
R> dbGetQuery(db, "SELECT version, count(*) FROM os_logs GROUP BY version ORDER BY version;")

           version count(*)
1 0.70.1111_Product        2
2       0.71.22_Dev        1
```